# Get the returned by a promise without using .then()

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

As the title says, I would like to get a value returned from within a `.then()` 
I have the following code:

```
function getResponse() {
    return rp(options)
    .then(function (response) {
        var result = [];
        // do manipulation and add data to result
        return result;
    })
}
```

Is it possible to get the value of result without using:

`getAWE().then((result) => {console.log(result)});`

I would like to use the value without having to use it within a `.then()` so I can create multiple functions like the above one and not have long chains of `.then()`

Comment: Use async await instead for cleaner code..

Comment: https://javascript.info/async-await